# #1052 - Column 'shop_id' in where clause is ambiguous как бороться?

Tags: sql, opencart

```
SELECT * FROM oc_products_in_shops AS shops
LEFT JOIN oc_product as products ON shops.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description as descr ON descr.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE shop_id = '2'
```

Следующий код выдает ошибку которая в заголовке. Мне нужно получить список товаров по совпадению product_id из одной таблицы с другой таблицей, а потом к этим товарам еще присоиденить таблицу с описанием (oc_products_description).
Как это сделать по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать имя конкретной таблицы, видимо название этой колонки встречается в нескольких таблицах

```
WHERE shops.shop_id = '2'

Верно, нужно указать ту таблицу из которой нужно брать значение shop_id и потом сравнивать значение этого поля с значениями других таблиц
```

Comment: Определенно что-то в этом есть что вы написали, вы правы, оно встречается там несколько раз, потому что в каждой таблице которые использованы в коде есть поле product_id. Сделал как вы посоветовали но теперь выдает сразу 2 результата одного и и того же поля с одинаковыми айди.

Comment: @Mike мне выводит 2 раза результат выполнения кода (как 2 разные записи) то есть я имею ввиду дубли не полей product_id или еще каких-то, а дубли самих результатов. Один результат показывается 2 раза. А то, сколько там всего выводит колонок - это не важно. Главное чтобы не показывало 2 раза одинаковые результаты выполнения скрипта.

Comment: @Mike вы не правильно меня понимаете. Таблица products_in_shops имеет всего одну запись, в которой идет shop_id = 2, product_id = 29 по этому мы получаем айди продукта, по нему берем информацию из таблицы "продукты" (товары) и по этому айди же надо получить описание к этому товару, которое имеет связь по product_id, другой там нет. А таких как product_id = 29 может быть несколько. Это идет таблица наличия товаров  в магазинах, просто описание находится в другой таблице к сожалению, иначе не было бы трудностей.

Comment: @ЖеняДанілов Запрос выводит всегда все записи которые найдет. Если по условиям склейки хотя бы в одной таблице более одной записи - значит результат будет перемножен. Это легко увидеть, если просмотреть все выбранные колонки. Задвоенные записи наверняка отличаются какой нибудь колонкой. Сделайте на sqlfiddle.com тестовую базу с записями и нормально задайте вопрос, с указанием какие данные вы намереваетесь получить. Кстати вам на ваш вопрос про одинаковые названия колонок уже ответили. так что вопрос исчерпан. Вся эта наша переписка никак не относится к основному вопросу